Should there really be a gap between mulch and tree trunks?
"Leave a gap between the mulch and the tree trunk to prevent the tree trunk from rotting" — this is the advice that I have read in almost all articles and books that have instructions for adding organic mulch to trees. Is there any evidence that the advice is valid?
I am questioning the advice because when I go into the tropical rainforest, I observe that there is a layer of mulch on the forest floor in the form of rotting leaves and wood. Nature does not create a gap between this mulch and the tree trunks, and yet the tree trunks are not rotting despite the very high moisture levels on the ground.

According to this site, there is no scientific evidence to support the theory that placing wood chips against a tree harms it. See points 9 and 10 of this post for clarification. This goes against everything I was taught 15+ year ago, but then again, how to successfully plant a containerized tree is almost the opposite now of what I was taught then, too...
